# Erro com vetores c# / {"Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."}

Tags: c#

Amigos estou vindo no php e começando desenvolver em C#.
As diferenças são muitos as ideias que tenho, quando vou aplicar dão erros, como o problema que tenho um combobox html que preenchido dinamicamente com dados do banco, que pensei separa o código que seria o value do combobox e colocar como um valor em cada posição de um array ate ae tudo bem mas não funciona.
A versão atual da o seguinte erro, alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolvo?

Da esse erro:

> "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Código;

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace empresa.UI.ProcessEmpresa
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AjaxPrazoMedioCliente
    /// </summary>
    public class AjaxPrazoMedioCliente : IHttpHandler
    {
        string[] v;//CRIACAO DO VETOR 
        public int i, j = 0;

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Grupo = Convert.ToString(context.Request.QueryString["codgrupo"]);
            temmontante = Convert.ToString(context.Request.QueryString["temmontante"]);
            selecionado = Convert.ToString(context.Request.QueryString["selecionado"]);
            temmontante = temmontante.Equals("") ? "0" : temmontante;
            HttpClient client = null;
            string retorno = string.Empty;
            if (client == null)
            {
                client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url_servidor"]);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage resultado = client.GetAsync("xyz/Venda/PrazoMedio/" + Grupo + "/" + temmontante).Result;
                retorno = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (resultado.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    if (retorno != "[]")
                {
                    sb.Append("<select name=\"txtpagpedido\" id=\"txtpagpedido\" onchange=\"HabilitarDescontoPromocional()\" style=\"width: 200px;\" >");
                    sb.Append("<option value=\"0\">Selecione..</option>");
                    JArray usuarioarrray = JArray.Parse(retorno);

                    foreach (JObject obj in usuarioarrray.Children<JObject>())
                    {
                        foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Properties())
                        {
                            if (v[i] != null)//MEU TRECHO PESQUISEI QUE TALVEZ SOLUCIONARIA O ERRO
                                if (Convert.ToString(prop.Value) != v[i])
                                    v[i] = prop.Value.ToString();
                                else
                                    break;

                            //vetor[i] = Convert.ToString(prop.Value.ToString());

                            switch (prop.Name)
                            {
                                case "e4_CODIGO":
                                    if (prop.Value.ToString().Equals(selecionado))
                                        sb.Append("<option value=\"" + Convert.ToString(prop.Value.ToString()) + "\" selected=\"selected\" >");
                                    else
                                        sb.Append("<option value=\"" + Convert.ToString(prop.Value.ToString()) + "\"  >");
                                    break;
                                case "e4_DESCRI":
                                    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(prop.Value.ToString()) + "</option>");
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }

                    sb.Append("</select>");

                }

            }

            context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: linha do erro??

Comment: Se tivesse a linha do erro, seria bem mais fácil identificar... Mas só de curiosidade, esse objeto "resultado" está vindo de onde?

Comment: Oi amigos obrigado, pelo retorno, vamos la, o pessoal estava fechando a empresa, eu tirei a linha por que tinha referencia da empresa, agora editei e coloquei o codigo completo e editado, agora da pra ter ideia, mas o tal retorno/resultado é um json com os dados, da base, que enche o combobox.

O erro da quando debugando ele chega na linha do vetor

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in xyz.UI.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

   em xyz.UI.Processxyz.Venda.AjaxPrazoMedioClienteEditar.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   em System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   em System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (v[i] != null)//MEU TRECHO PESQUISEI QUE TALVEZ SOLUCIONARIA O ERRO
```

Certamente esta faltando você declara o tamanho do seu vetor, o erro pode até não ser esse, mas é o mais provável que seja com as informações que tem.

Comment: mas a quantidade é dinâmica! nao posso declarar, tem alguma ideia eu coloquei estático, mas deu erro acho que pela diferença do total que declarei com o valores colocados,

 private string[] v = new string[100];

Comment: Se você quer algo dinâmico, use uma lista ao invés de array. Ficaria assim: List<string> v = new List<string>();

Answer (score 0):

O problema esta nesse combo tirar os valores repetidos

> Selecione..
>   28
>   21/28/35
>   21
>   49
>   42/56/70
>   28/42/56
>   28/42/56
>   28/42/56
>   28/56
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   28/56/84
>   ANTECIPADO
>   ANTECIPADO
>   ANTECIPADO
>   ANTECIPADO
>   ANTECIPADO
>   ANTECIPADO
>   42/56
>   28/42/56/70
>   28/42
>   14
>   14/28/42
>   14/28/42
>   28/42/56/70/84
>   28/42/56/70/84
>   28/42/56/70/84
>   35/42/49
>   10
>   28/35/42/49
>   56
>   56
>   56
>   56
>   35
>   28/35/42
>   28/35/42/49/56
>   28/35/42/49/56
>   28/35/42/49/56
>   28+7D 7X
>   42
>   35/42/49/56
>   35/42/49/56/63
>   42/49/56
>   42/49/56/63/70
>   42/70/90
>   14/28
>   25/56
>   28/42/56/70/84

Answer (score 0):

> colocando um valor estatico/fixo deu o seguinte erro

```
    private string[] v = new string[100];
```

An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in xyz.UI.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: O índice estava fora dos limites da matriz.

{"O índice estava fora dos limites da matriz."}

Answer (score 0):

Porque você está usando um array como retorno ??

Poderia usar uma lista de string e no final o método `ToArray` do pacote `System.Linq`

assim:
`lista.ToArray();`

Aparentemente existem outros erros nesse código mas é melhor você disponibilizar a exceção completa.